# get div class name of context in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make my first chrome extension with manifest version 3. I am trying to get info about the open tab page.
I figured out how to get all the Header-tags (H1,H2,H3,...) of the context.

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6', context).each(function() {
            headings.push({
                text: ($(this).text() || '').toString().trim(),
            });
        });
```

But I want to get the className of all div-tags.

When I do

```
$('div', context).each(function() {
            divs.push({
                text: ($(this).text() || '').toString().trim(),
            });
        });
```

I only get the info between the tags

```
<div>I get this </div>
```

but I want to get "classname"

```
<div class="classname"></div>
```

Comment: Try with `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div=>{divs.push({text:div.className});});`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you try get text value of the elements in side the loop .
Please use

```
    $('div', context).each(function() {
            if($(this).hasAttribute("class") {

               var cls = $(this).getAttribute("class")
               divs.push({
                     text: cls ,
                      });
          }
            
        });
```